# Couldn't find part of path error IIS Express - C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\Image\QrCode.jpg

Tags: c#, pdf, iis, itext

I'm trying to save an aspx-page to a PDF. 
It contains a QR-code (as an image) and some text. I am using iTextSharp and QRCode Library as nuget. Visual studio 2012.

My problem is that when i run this, I get an error (when it hits "pdfDoc.Close") and it says Couldn't find part of path "C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\Image\QrCode.jpg.".
I'm translating this from Swedish so I think it is correct. 
I'm saving the QR-image locally in the project in a folder called Image. But it wants it in IIS Express\Image instead. Why is that? 
The PDF is being saved, but only with the text.

Here is the code I use to create, save and use my QR-Image.

```
            QRCodeEncoder encoder = new QRCodeEncoder();
            Bitmap img = encoder.Encode(objectList[95].ToString());

img.Save(@"C:\Users\My name\Documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\EmptyQR\EmptyQR\Image\QrCode.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            QRImage.ImageUrl = @"~/Image/QrCode.jpg";
```

And here's the code I use to save as a PDF. (
The folder "Files" is located in my project.)

```
   protected void btnExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FileStream file = new FileStream(Server.MapPath("~/Files/") + "Test.PDF", FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write);
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        Panel1.RenderControl(hw);
        StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
        Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 100f, 0f);
        HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, file);
        pdfDoc.Open();
        htmlparser.Parse(sr);
        pdfDoc.Close();
        file.Close();
    }
```

Here you can see the HTML code.

```
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
```

*I have to have this space here, or else the code above wouldn't show.*

```
        <div id="qr">
            <div class="qrImage">
                <asp:Image runat="server" ID="QRImage" />
            </div>
            <div class="information">
                <h1>Real Estate</h1>
                <p class="productName prodInfo">RL-B7-103</p>
                <p class="prodInfo">Brandagsventilator, elektronisk styrd</p>
                <p class="prodInfo">BRA 2-B (Mtrl, center, uh, detaljmåleri)</p>
                <p class="prodInfo">Takplan</p>
            </div>

        </div>
    </asp:Panel>
    <asp:Button ID="btnExport" runat="server" Text="Export"
        OnClick="btnExport_Click" />


</form>
```

Comment: Remember, you are asking iText to parse a string, not a URL, so iText has no idea where paths like `src="XYZ.jPG"` should start from. If you are going to continue to use the obsolete and unsupported and very fragile `HTMLWorker` then [see this answer for setting a base URL](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14707465/231316).

Comment: I'm not sure I follow? Do you mean I have to pass in a real URL and not a string? Sorry, English isn't my my first language.
I will look up the HTMLWorker. I don't want to use it.

Comment: You are doing it correctly but you need to tell iText where your HTML document's "root" is. HTMLWorker was replaced many years ago by the much more powerful XMLWorker.

Comment: Okay, I'll try to use XMLWorker instead. Thank you, if I don't make it work I'll come back.

Comment: I now use a completely different code, but it makes the PDF look great, the only thing missing is the QR-Image. Not sure how to get that to work, but it made a huge difference with XMLWorker. Thank you for that.